# Add a repository, but hold updates of an individual package

Tags: nautilus, package-management, ppa, nautilus-elementary

I am adding the elementary-desktop ppa (https://launchpad.net/~elementaryart/+archive/elementarydesktop) because it keeps track of the latest updates for several applications I use. However, I do not want `nautilus` to be upgraded to the `elementary-desktop`'s version.

I understand that I can use dpkg or aptitude to "hold" updates to `nautilus`, but will that also hold updates from `Ubuntu`'s repositories?

I'm looking for an ideal solution that would give me updates from `Ubuntu`'s repository, but ignore updates from `elementary-desktop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Firstly open Synaptic package manager .
- Now select the package you want to hold from a specific repo .
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> .
- Select the version from the standard repos .
  [image: Synaptic screenshot]
- Now you will only get updates from the standard repos on that package .

Answer (score 2):

If you prefere the terminal, you can do it this way:

```
echo "PACKAGENAME hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```